Pm2 server is automatically turning off at any time on ssh of hostinger
0|blog-api  |     at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) {
0|blog-api  |   errno: -104,
0|blog-api  |   code: 'ECONNRESET',
0|blog-api  |   syscall: 'read',
0|blog-api  |   fatal: true
0|blog-api  | }

And I can't understand what is the issue. I also tried asking chatgpt it showed a solution of using http. I tried it but failed, it didn't even run the server.
I tried this code.
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
require('dotenv').config();
const port = process.env.PORT;
const mysql = require('mysql');


const connection =  mysql.createConnection({
    host: `${process.env.HOSTNAME}`,
    user: `${process.env.USERNAME}`,
    password: `${process.env.PASS}`,
    database: `${process.env.DATABASE}`
  });
  
connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Connected to the remote database!');
  });

  const getBlogs = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      await connection.query("SELECT * FROM Blog", function (err, result, fields) {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.json(result);
        })
    }
    catch (err) {
      res.json(err);
    }
  
  }

app.get('/',getBlogs);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});


Hard to judge what is causing the error (especially without a complete stacktrace of the error). But there are various things that look wrong. Like the MySQL connection handling and the usage of await on a function that takes a callback.

It is solved now issue was the timeout MySQL connection was getting timeout  and it was disconnecting I created a reconnecting function and also use connection pool to stay connected.

I assumed that the problem is related to that, as I said the handling of the MySQL connection looked wrong. And when you have a solution to your problem, don't write it as a comment, write it as an actual answer and accept it as an answer.
